How can I number a chunk's code but not its output?
I'm writing an online book (bs4_book) with the bookdown package in RMarkdown. Inside the markdown there are Python chunks with simple operations like importing libraries and arithmetic calculations. I've been looking for a way to make the lines inside the Python chunks numbered by changing parameters inside the style.css file. Although I succeeded, this method also numbers the output of the cells, and I personally don't like it.
I know there must be a way to define it inside the .css file, but I don't know the language.
Here's my style.css file:
p.caption {
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p code {
  white-space: inherit;
}
pre {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
pre code {
  white-space: inherit;
}
pre.sourceCode {
    counter-reset: line;
    line-height: 0.8; 
}
pre.sourceCode > code > span {
    display: block;
    counter-increment: line;
}
pre.sourceCode > code > span:before {
    content: counter(line);
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    color: #888;
}
pre.output, pre.verbatim {
  counter-reset: none !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  list-style-type: none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
pre.output > code > span:before, pre.verbatim > code > span:before {
  content: none !important;
}

My _output.yml:
bookdown::bs4_book:
  css: style.css
  config:
    numbering:
      fig: true
  theme:
    bootswatch: litera 
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default

My _bookdown.yml file:
book_filename: "online-book"
number_sections: true
fig_caption: true
new_session: true
before_chapter_script: _common.R
delete_merged_file: true

The chunk configuration:
library(knitr) 
library(reticulate)
reticulate::use_condaenv("python", required = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, warning = FALSE, comment = '>>', message = FALSE, highlight = TRUE, cache.lazy = FALSE)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)

A example Python chunk:
a = 5
b = 3
c = a/b

print(type(a),type(b),type(c))

Python chunk html code:
<div class="sourceCode" id="cb2"><pre class="sourceCode python"><code class="sourceCode python"><span id="cb2-1"><a href="prueba.html#cb2-1" tabindex="-1"></a>a <span class="op">=</span> <span class="dv">5</span></span>
<span id="cb2-2"><a href="prueba.html#cb2-2" tabindex="-1"></a>b <span class="op">=</span> <span class="dv">3</span></span>
<span id="cb2-3"><a href="prueba.html#cb2-3" tabindex="-1"></a>c <span class="op">=</span> a<span class="op">/</span>b</span>
<span id="cb2-4"><a href="prueba.html#cb2-4" tabindex="-1"></a></span>
<span id="cb2-5"><a href="prueba.html#cb2-5" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="bu">print</span>(<span class="bu">type</span>(a),<span class="bu">type</span>(b),<span class="bu">type</span>(c))</span>
<span id="cb2-6"><a href="prueba.html#cb2-6" tabindex="-1"></a><span class="co">#&gt; &lt;class 'int'&gt; &lt;class 'int'&gt; &lt;class 'float'&gt;</span></span></code></pre></div>

Output:
1| a = 5

2| b = 3

3| c = a/b

4|

5| print(type(a),type(b),type(c))

6| >> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'float'>

Desire outuput:
1| a = 5

2| b = 3

3| c = a/b

4|

5| print(type(a),type(b),type(c))

>> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'float'>

Hope this helps.

You should show us a snippet of the HTML generated for a code chunk that includes output, so we know what bookdown is using as CSS classes on the various kinds of lines.

Ok, I'm gonna add my configuration

Sorry for not being clear:  I meant I'd like to see the HTML code from the .html file, not how it is being displayed.  It should look something like `a = 5
b = 3
c = a/b
print(type(a),type(b),type(c))
`

My bad, I'm going to upload it too!

From the posted HTML code, it appears that the Python output is in a <span> labelled with class="co".  I'm no CSS expert, but I believe the way to do this is to modify your CSS code to something like this:
pre.sourceCode > code > span.not('co') {
    display: block;
    counter-increment: line;
}
pre.sourceCode > code > span.not('co'):before {
    content: counter(line);
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    color: #888;
}

Hopefully someone who does know CSS better will comment or correct this if I have the syntax wrong.

I've been trying this code and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Do I need to make otherchanges to my hmtl file?

I doubt it, but you might need other changes to your style.css file.
